# How to make Visual Studio Code use config from ~/.zshrc so it applies to NPM scripts?

Tags: macos, npm, visual-studio-code, zsh

In `~/.zshrc`, I have the following alias.

```sh
alias mongod="mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf"
```

In `package.json`, I have the following script.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "mongod": "mongod --quiet"
  }
}
```

Problem is the `mongod` alias doesn’t override `mongod`.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Maybe try utilizing the [npm config](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/config) command to set the value of the [script-shell](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#script-shell) setting to the path to `zsh`, e.g. run `npm config set script-shell "$(which zsh)"`. However, you may want to firstly run `npm config get script-shell`, so you can take note of the shell currently being used - just in case you need to revert. By default npm runs npm scripts using `sh` on _*nix_, and `cmd` on Windows.

Comment: @RobC That was promising... but unfortunately doesn’t work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure if `zsh` provides a `-c` option like bash does. If it does however, try defining the `mongod` script in _package.json_ as `"mongod": "zsh -c \"mongod --quiet\""`

Comment: @RobC Actually, running `zsh -c "mongod --quiet"` ignores `~/.zshrc`, even in iTerm2... No sure why running `mongod` in  iTerm2 uses the alias though... I’m new to zsh.

Comment: Try defining the mongod script in _package.json_ to also use the `-i` option. for instance: `"mongod": "zsh -i -c \"mongod --quiet\""`

Comment: @RobC : The `-i` is cruicial, because (1) The OP has placed the alias definition into.zshrc and this file is only processed by interactive shells, and (2) aliases are also only processed in interactive shells, unless the shell is configured to use aliases.

Comment: @user1934428 Do you know how to make npm use an interactive shell? Sounds promising!

Comment: I don't know about `npm`. The shell is interactive, if it is started using the `-i` option, or (I think) if it is attached to a terminal. If you can arrange for the former, it will work. I hope that you don't want to get an interactive shell used by npm for the sole reason, that your aliases from .zshrc are processed. This would really be a misuse of this feature.

Comment: fwiw - using `chsh` to change my shell to `zsh`, then defining my npm script as per my last comment; `"mongod": "zsh -i -c \"<some_aliased_command>\""` - did work successfully for me. However, for test purposes in `~/.zshrc` I just aliased a builtin command - I don't have `mongod` available to fully test further. @sunknudsen - If you have any error logs etc, it may be helpful to share with the community.

Comment: @RobC Thanks for your help. Ideally, I’m trying to avoid using `"mongod": "zsh -i -c \"<some_aliased_command>\""` to not impose zsh on other contributors. I would love to find a user configurable way to override `mongod` using an alias.

Comment: @sunknudsen - Sure, I understand your reasoning for why you would not want to impose `zsh` on others - and what I provided does exactly that.  However your question implies otherwise, (i.e. that was never a consideration), because you've already aliased a command in `.zshrc` and you've  mentioned _"Problem is the `mongod` alias doesn’t override `mongod`."_ - effectively you've already imposed `zsh` on others.